# How to Group records by DateRange

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

How to group records by date range in sql ?

Conside this Table Structure.

```
 Key       ID       VISITDATE
 1         1        2011-01-07
 2         1        2011-01-09
 3         2        2011-01-10
 4         1        2011-01-12
 5         3        2011-01-12
 6         1        2011-01-18
 7         2        2011-01-21
 9         1        2011-02-28
 10        2        2011-03-21
 11        1        2011-01-06
 12        1        2011-02-29
```

I need to get the number of occurrences. if you have two visits within 10 days for the same id then only one visit should be counted.
so for the example given the number of occurrences for id 1 = 3 (01/06,01/18,02/28)

A Recursive CTE query is highly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't really described what your range is. Is it a week? Does it matter if the range starts or blows through a weekend? Also why do you care if it's a recursive CTE or not? Isn't it more important that it delivers the answer you're looking for? Also, can you show the *result* you want from the given sample data, instead of just describing it? (As an aside, 2011-02-29 is not a valid date!)

Comment: Just to clarify, if you have vists on days `(0, 5, 10, 15)` you appear to be grouping them as `(0, 5, 10), (15)` even though the third and fourth visits are within 10 days of each other.  Is that correct?  And is it important that you get `(0, 5, 10), (15)` rather than `(0), (5, 10, 15)`?

Comment: Still not clear why 1/6 and 1/15 are considered separate. Those are "within 10 days" aren't they?

Comment: @dems . i need to group them by the first vist on a group. so if i have `(0,5,10,15)` then grouping  will be `(0,5,10)` and `(15)`

Comment: @Aaron, I think i did a mistake there ..with 1/6 and 1/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you asked for a recursive CTE but without the new windowing enhancements in SQL Server 2012 (FIRST_VALUE() etc.) I think it is going to be a bear to write that way when you have to keep track of not only the previous row but also earlier rows simultaneously. Here is a cursor version that I believe achieves what you want:

```
DECLARE @f TABLE([Key] INT, ID INT, VISITDATE DATE);

INSERT @f VALUES
  (1 ,1,'2011-01-07'), (2 ,1,'2011-01-09'), (3 ,2,'2011-01-10'), (4 ,1,'2011-01-12'),
  (5 ,3,'2011-01-12'), (6 ,1,'2011-01-18'), (7 ,2,'2011-01-21'), (9 ,1,'2011-02-28'), 
  (10,2,'2011-03-21'), (11,1,'2011-01-06'), (12,1,'2011-03-01');

DECLARE @ID INT, @dt DATE;

DECLARE @result TABLE(ID INT, FirstDate DATE, VisitCount INT);

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR SELECT ID, VISITDATE FROM @f ORDER BY ID, VISITDATE;

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID, @dt;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM @result WHERE ID = @ID
            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, FirstDate, @dt) <= 10 -- maybe < 10?
    )
    INSERT @result SELECT @ID, @dt, 1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID, @dt;
END

SELECT ID, FirstDate FROM @result;

SELECT ID, VisitCount = COUNT(*) FROM @result GROUP BY ID;

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Results:

```
ID          FirstDate
----------- ----------
1           2011-01-06
1           2011-01-18
1           2011-02-28
2           2011-01-10
2           2011-01-21
2           2011-03-21
3           2011-01-12


ID          VisitCount
----------- -----------
1           3
2           3
3           1
```

Yes, I know you're always warned not to talk to strangers and to stay away from cursors, but in some cases they're the most straightforward solution (and can sometimes perform better than multiple scans that a set-based solution might incur).

Answer (score 1):

You don't clarify how the date ranges will be defined

If starting the ranges from today you can do it like this:

```
SELECT     id, COUNT(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(dd, visitdate, GETDATE()) / 10) AS Expr1
FROM         test
GROUP BY id
```

If you want to start the ranges from the latest date on the data you can do it like this

```
DECLARE @maxdate as datetime
SET @maxdate = (select MAX(visitdate) from test)

SELECT     id, COUNT(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(dd, visitdate, @maxdate) / 10) 
FROM         test
GROUP BY id
```

A query like this will do the trick for the case @Dems pointed

```
SELECT id, count(DISTINCT visitdate)
FROM (
    SELECT   id, visitdate,
        (SELECT MAX(visitdate) 
        FROM test AS t 
        WHERE t.id = test.id AND t.visitdate<test.visitdate) AS prev_date
    FROM     test ) as temp
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, prev_date, visitdate) > 10 OR prev_date IS NULL
GROUP BY id
```

the above query doesn't count the records with the same id and for which another record exists with a date smaller by ten days

If you want to split the calendar starting from the min date for each id you can do the following

```
SELECT     t.id, COUNT(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(dd, mindate, visitdate) / 10) 
FROM         test as t JOIN 
  (SELECT id, MIN(visitdate) AS mindate FROM test GROUP BY id) as mindates
    ON t.id = mindates.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: The range is "10 days from the othe records", it is not a matter of quantising a calendar into 10 day long blocks.

Comment: @Dems: you have a point but I think that the original post doesn't clarify that

Comment: @Dems I get your point but I find "within 10 days" a little vague and ambiguous (in fact 10 may have just been an example and not his exact boundary). Are Jan 1 and Jan 11 "within 10 days" or "within 11 days"? Hopefully the OP can specify more concretely.

Comment: Whether the boundary condition is inclusive or exclusive is unclear, but the code difference is likely to be just `<=` vs `<`.  That the 10 day window is a relative period seems reasonably strong to me.  Having a window from 1st to 10th and another from 11th to 20th (inclusive) would imply that visits on the 10th and 11th are considered unrelated.  Which just seems nutz ***That's an official technical term ;)***

Comment: The dates should should start from Min(date) for a particular id

Comment: @AshleyJohn: check the revised answer please

Comment: Three of these solutions provide a count of 7 for ID 1, the other provides a count of 2. The expected answer is 3. For the other IDs, they're right, but I think that's just because the ranges involved with those IDs are less problematic.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I have changed the last date to 2011-02-28 since 2011-02-29 is not a valid date. With this modification all the queries except the second return count 2 for id = 1, the second query returns count 3 for id = 1, which is also correct for that's query logic

Comment: I get 6/3/1, 6/3/1, 2/3/1, 6/3/1 with your queries. None of them yields 3 for ID = 1. (I changed the last row to March 1 but it shouldn't change the correct output.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Running the first query
'SELECT * FROM test'

Key  id    visitdate
----- ---- ----------
1    1     2011-01-07 
2    1     2011-01-09 
3    2     2011-01-10 
4    1     2011-01-12 
5    3     2011-01-12 
6    1     2011-01-15 
7    2     2011-01-21 
9    1     2011-02-28 
10   2     2011-03-21 
11   1     2011-01-06 
12   1     2011-02-28 

>SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(dd, visitdate, GETDATE()) / 10) AS Count FROM test GROUP BY id

id     Count
------ -----
1      2
2      3
3      1'

Comment: Sorry, with that exact query I get 6, not 2, in the first row. Using @f as provided in my answer rather than 'test'...

Comment: @AaronBertrand, this very strange indeed, can't really explain it

Comment: On SQL Server 2012, I get 6/3/1. On SQL Server 2008 R2, I get 3/3/1.  I can't explain that either. (Note the cursor version I posted works correctly on both.) Will investigate...

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 it needs to be `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (DATEDIFF ... /10))` - will look into this further still.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I have checked the first query on your data, the result is 3/3/1 for ids 1,2,3 respectivly

Comment: Yep, I think we have discovered a bug in SQL Server 2012 RC0. I will post when I have more details.

Comment: According to @SQL_Kiwi this is a bug involving a new optimizer rule introduced in SQL Server 2012 (and it seems to have been corrected already). If you want to read more about it see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/04/is-distinct-aggregation-still-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: @pater The proposed solution doesnot work in edge cases.Consider mindate = `(01\02)`. and say that you have got visits in '01\18` and `(01\22). They both should be in the same occurrence.but that division by 10 put it in two diff occurrences

Comment: @AshleyJohn, You don't mention which one of the queries doesn't work. Despite that, I 've checked the queries with the above mentioned values. Queries 2 and 3 return count=2 for the values you mention. Queries 1 and 4 return count = 3 but this is the correct value, since both queries split the calendar to ten days intervals, the first one starting from today and the latter starting from the minimum date. If starting from the minimum date (1\2), the split will give three intervals (1/2-10/2,11/2-20/2, 21/2-2/3) and therefore the three days you mention will all correspond to different intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scalar function that returns the same date for all dates within a given range and then group by that.

Comment: the function depends not the single date alone.it just cant work like a Month() or Year(). it depends on its previous date as well.

Comment: Either way you should be able to write a function that provides the necessary output value for you to group on.   Overall you'll want to group by `dateFunction(VISITDATE), id` surely?  Will have a think.

Comment: @twilson - If so, may I suggest that you write an example of the function and its use?